# Ordering of classes in puppet

Tags: puppet

I need to execute class mysql,tomcat before I execute code in class mypackage. In my site.pp I have

```
node 'node1' {
include mysql,mypackage,tomcat
}
```

How do I ensure the order of execution mysql->tomcat->mypackage

I tried putting this in /etc/puppet/modules/mypackage/manifests/init.pp but it did not work.

```
class mypackage {
    include mysql
    include tomcat
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please read this article about [ordering in puppet](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html). 
**UPDATE:**
I recommend defining ordering relationships in your `site.pp`

```
    node 'node1' {
        include mysql,mypackage,tomcat
        Class['mysql'] -> Class['tomcat'] -> Class['mypackage']
    }
```

Please be aware of [dependency cycles](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#dependency-cycles). It is really easy to create such cycle in puppet.

Comment: I just would not recommend the `require` function to anyone, ever.

Comment: @FelixFrank Could you briefly explain what is wrong with require function ? I never have problems with it.

Comment: Chaining is a better concept for reciprocal form or a notifying form, where require has none of that, so you can't control how those resources are installed.  require works, but it isn't ideal.

Comment: Sure, chaining is better. That's why I recommended it at first place. But still I don't see why require function should not be used at all.

Comment: It's just that it has no benefit over conventional means of ordering, but can easily introduce dependency cycles (as you note in your answer) that can be extra hard to trace.

Comment: Ok. Using require function seems to be controversial. I decided to remove it from my answer.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this answer over class{'mysql':} -> class{'tomcat':} -> class{'mypackage':} ?

Comment: @Jimadine If you do it like that, you won't be able to use other manifests that also try to declare those classes (duplicate class declaration error) where an include would still allow that. See https://serverfault.com/a/749103 for instance.